# Transform a data.table with vertical relationships into a table with horizontal relationships

Tags: r, data.table

How can I pass elegantly from table1 (with vertical relationships) to table2 (with horizontal relationships)?

```
library(data.table)
# vertical relationship
table1 <- data.table(id=1:4,father=c(NA,"Vladimir","Boris","John"),individual=c("Vladimir","Boris","John","Will"))
table1
```

[image]

```
# horizontal relationship
table2 <- data.table(id=1:4,greatgrandfather= c(NA,NA,NA,"Vladimir"), grandfather=c(NA,NA,"Vladimir","Boris"),father=c(NA,"Vladimir","Boris","John"),individual=c("Vladimir","Boris","John","Will"))
table2
```

[image]

Here goes the ugly solution I came up with:

```
# ugly solution
temporary.table <- table1[,.(father,individual)]

names(temporary.table)<- c("grandfather","father")
new.table <- merge(table1,temporary.table,by="father",all.x=T)

names(temporary.table)<- c("greatgrandfather","grandfather")
new.table <- merge(new.table,temporary.table,by="grandfather",all.x=T)

ugly.solution <- new.table[order(id)][,.(id,greatgrandfather,grandfather,father,individual)]
ugly.solution
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Reduce** Define the `father_of` function which looks up its argument's father.  Also define `nms`, the output's column names (except for `"id"`).

Then use `Reduce` to recursively apply `father_of`.

Finally put everything together in a data table.

Note that by simply modifying `nms` we can have more or fewer ancestors in the result.

```
father_of <- function(x, ...) table1[, father[match(x, individual)] ]

nms <- c("greatgrandfather", "grandfather", "father", "individual")

r <- Reduce(father_of, init = table1$individual, nms[-1], acc = TRUE)    

table1[, c(.(id = id), setNames(rev(r), nms))]
```

giving:

```
   id greatgrandfather grandfather   father individual
1:  1               NA          NA       NA   Vladimir
2:  2               NA          NA Vladimir      Boris
3:  3               NA    Vladimir    Boris       John
4:  4         Vladimir       Boris     John       Will
```

**2) Recursion** An alternative using the same definitions of `father_of` and `nms` employs recursion in the function `rec`.  The length of `nms` controls the number of generations, as before.

```
rec <- function(x, n) if (ncol(x) == n) x else Recall(cbind(father_of(x[[1]]), x), n)

r <- rec(table1[, .(individual)], length(nms))
table1[, c(.(id = id), setNames(r, nms))]
```

giving:

```
   id greatgrandfather grandfather   father individual
1:  1               NA          NA       NA   Vladimir
2:  2               NA          NA Vladimir      Boris
3:  3               NA    Vladimir    Boris       John
4:  4         Vladimir       Boris     John       Will
```

**UPDATE** Fixed.  Added (2).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your solution is that ugly. But maybe you could make the rename process a little more explicit. Here is how it looks like rewriting `merge` with `data.table` join syntax, which saves some variable assignment by chaining the two joins together:

```
table1[, .(grandgrandfather = father, grandfather = individual)][
    table1[, .(grandfather = father, father = individual)][
        table1, on = .(father)
    ], 
    on = .(grandfather)
]

#   grandgrandfather grandfather   father id individual
#1:               NA          NA       NA  1   Vladimir
#2:               NA          NA Vladimir  2      Boris
#3:               NA    Vladimir    Boris  3       John
#4:         Vladimir       Boris     John  4       Will
```

---

In case you need a lot more generations up than what is feasible by writing join manually, you can do recursive join with a for loop:

```
find_ancestors <- function(table, n) {
    final <- copy(table)
    setnames(final, 'father', 'father_1')
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        name_up <- paste('father', i:(i+1), sep = "_")
        final <- table[, setNames(.(individual, father), name_up)][final, on = name_up[1]]
    }
    final
}

find_ancestors(table1, 3)
#   father_3 father_4 father_2 father_1 id individual
#1:       NA       NA       NA       NA  1   Vladimir
#2:       NA       NA       NA Vladimir  2      Boris
#3:       NA       NA Vladimir    Boris  3       John
#4: Vladimir       NA    Boris     John  4       Will

find_ancestors(table1, 5)
#   father_5 father_6 father_4 father_3 father_2 father_1 id individual
#1:       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA  1   Vladimir
#2:       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA Vladimir  2      Boris
#3:       NA       NA       NA       NA Vladimir    Boris  3       John
#4:       NA       NA       NA Vladimir    Boris     John  4       Will

find_ancestors(table1, 2)
#   father_2 father_3 father_1 id individual
#1:       NA       NA       NA  1   Vladimir
#2:       NA       NA Vladimir  2      Boris
#3: Vladimir       NA    Boris  3       John
#4:    Boris Vladimir     John  4       Will
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom, your version does look cleaner! 

My data has up to 16 generations, so the multiple merge appears quickly messy..